# ¿Como puedo recuperar el boot menu y disco duro?

Tags: ubuntu, windows, boot, grub2

Yo anteriormente (al día de hoy) tenia un disco duro (D) de 1TB, dentro del cual tenia una particion para ubuntu y kali linux, pero la mayor parte del tiempo estaba en ubuntu.

[image]

El día de ayer por las prisas, estaba en ubuntu y apague la computadora desde el boton de apagar. A la maedia hora intente prenderla pero ya no aparecia el boot menu, solo la consola GRUB y no podia salirme a menos que ejecutara el comando "exit".

Me manda a Windows, checo los discos y solo estaba este, me fui directo a la consola para checar las particiones y tampoco estaba. Sigo si entender como se borro todo (visualmente, porque se que esta guardado todo en alguna parte de la memoria de la computadora.

He intentado en links como el siguiente, pero no encuentro/tengo la sig linea:
`linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-20`

https://askubuntu.com/questions/883992/stuck-at-grub-command-line

No se si se daño el MBR o el boot loader, me interesa recuperar solo ciertas cosas aunque despues tenga que restaurar todo, algun consejo.

Comment: Si tenías dual boot, trata con un liveISO (desde una USB) y busca cómo reconstruir el arranque. Pinta que se dañó y Windows lo arregló a su manera...

Comment: Gracias!!, deja lo intento!!

Comment: Hola, amigo te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat]

Comment: tu problema esta relacionada al manejo de aplicaciones en el sistema operativo, y no a algo relacionado a los objetivos del sitio (Desarrollo y programación).